# Qt: passing objects to every window

Tags: c++, qt

Im a beginner at C++ since I'm a Java-Dev. I'm learning Qt right now.
Now I want in my widget application on central object for holding special functionality (for example a bunch of methods for sending different network-command or something like that). In my mainwindow.cpp I've got this

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //...
    BusinessLogic* bl = new BusinessLogic;
    bl->setMyValue(44);
    this->setBusinessLogic(bl);
    this->getBusinessLogic();

    //...
}

BusinessLogic* MainWindow::getBusinessLogic()
{
    return this->bl;
}

void MainWindow::setBusinessLogic(BusinessLogic* newbl)
{
    this->bl = newbl;
}
```

Where BusinessLogic.cpp is the class which I want to access from all windows in my application. So in my Dialog which get opend when the pushButton is clicked, I try to use the businesslogic instance like this in the constructor

```
Dialog::Dialog(QDialog *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    //...   
    ((MainWindow*)parent)->getBusinessLogic();
}
```

Unfortunately the program crashes everytime the dialog get instanciated (the line with `((MainWindow*)parent)->getBusinessLogic();` get called.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods for achieving your goal(all depends on your requirements) but one approach is you can create Singleton class of your BusinessLogic and then access it anywhere. have a look [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/1). **OR** you can also pass object of class one class to another. **OR** you can use signal slot mechanism.

For you best Solution can be

```
Class BLogic{
public:
    static BLogic* instance(){
       static BLogic ins;
       return &ins;
    }
    void setVal(int v){ 
        val = v;
    }
private:
    BLogic(){}
    int val;
};
```

Now you can call functions of BLogic from any class like

```
BLogic::instance()->setVal(10);
```

**OR** Example of passing objects can be

```
class ClassA
{
public:
   void setClassB(ClassB *ob){
      m_classB = ob;
   }
   ClassB* getClassB(){
      return m_classB;
   }
private:
   ClassB* m_classB;
};

class ClassB
{
public:
   void setClassA(ClassA *ob){
      m_classA = ob;
   }
   ClassA* getClassA(){
      return m_classA;
   }
private:
   ClassA* m_classA;
};
```

Now from main.cpp

```
ClassA* obA = new ClassA;
ClassB* obB = new ClassB;
obA->setClassB(obB);
obB->setClassA(obA);
```

Comment: _you can also pass object of class one class to another._. Can you give me an example for that?

Comment: @MarcM have a look again

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass a zero parent or a dangling pointer to the dialog.

But more seriously, verify your assumptions:

```
qDebug() << "the parent object is" << parent;
auto p = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);
if (p)
    p->getBusinessLogic();
```

Debug output will give you some idea of whether a parent is set, and of what type it is at the moment. Remember that during the construction of a `MainWindow` instance, it goes through being different types (quite literally). So depending on when you construct the child, you might get a `parent` of type `QWidget*` or `QMainWindow*` or `MainWindow*`. During the destruction you could even get a `QObject*` parent!

Comment: That means that the `parent` is either not set or is not a `MainWindow`. You can't use it either way. This tells you that your problem is elsewhere, and only manifests in this part of code. Once you fix **the real bug**, the `if` condition will become true! Don't blame this answer for pointing you to the source of your problem :)

Comment: +1 This will work(!) if the rest of your code is valid. Always make sure that your pointers are valid, this is C++.